# Python: Unittest testing based on Docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, docstring

I am new to using unittest for testing my modules. Usually docstrings already contain a lot of useful info such as the datatypes expected by a function or the datatype of the return value. E.g.

```
def myFunc(parmA,paramB):
    """
    This function is awesome
    :param paramA: int
    :param paramB: str
    :return:
    """
```

Would there be a way to automatically test for raises TypeError when the wrong datatype is supplied, based on the information in the docstring?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html

Comment: Oh, you mean static type checking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools for static type checking in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025714/tools-for-static-type-checking-in-python)

Comment: Go for [python type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), it has its own syntax for it. Then go for one of the tools as @mkrieger1 suggested.