# Python Library for Function Interfaces?

Tags: python, interface, abstract-class, abc

I'm wondering if there's an existing Python libary/technique for enforcing function interfaces/"contracts".  Something like ABC but for functions.

E.g.  An example with made-up syntax:

```
@implements(i_state_updater)
def my_update(position, state, forces):
    ... 
    return new_position, new_state
```

Where

```
@declare_interface
def i_state_updater(position, state, forces):
    """
    :param position: ...
    :returns: ....
    """
```

So that when I pass this function as an argument I can verify it, eg

```
def compute_trajectory(update_func, n_steps, initial_state):
    """
    :param update_func: An i_state_updater
    ...
    """
    assert update_func.implements(i_state_updater)
```

Python's existing abc module does something like this, but only for classes.  Is there an equivalent out there for functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyContract seems like a library that you would want to look into.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyContracts

See also

- [Tools for static type checking in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025714/tools-for-static-type-checking-in-python)
- [How to use type hints in python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356784/how-to-use-type-hints-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I was looking for - somehow my searching hasn't found it before.  Thanks.